# D3 collpse tree on angular 8

Tags: angular, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to create a tree using d3v5 library.

However i'm having problems when creating the collapse/expand effect.
I saw a lot of examples online, but many of them are not compatible with d3v5.

My test in github: https://github.com/FabioBiao/D3-tree
One component with the tree and another with one of my tests of making the update tree, to collapse/expand.

So how should i aproach this issue, to update the node and update the visualization of it.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks